# problem with JPA EntityManager

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink, entitymanager

i am new to JPA, i have a problem with my JPA .
i have used the entity manager as follows:

```
1: package com.icesoft.icefaces.samples.datatable.jpa;
    2: 
    3: import java.util.logging.Level;
    4: import java.util.logging.Logger;
    5: 
    6: import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    7: import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
    8: import javax.persistence.Persistence;
    9: import javax.persistence.Query;
   10: /**
   11:  * @author MyEclipse Persistence Tools
   12:  */
   13: public class EntityManagerHelper {
   14:     
   15:     private static final EntityManagerFactory emf; 
   16:     private static final ThreadLocal<EntityManager> threadLocal;
   17:     private static final Logger logger;
   18:     
   19:     static {
   20:         emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("tutorialPU");         
   21:         threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<EntityManager>();
   22:         logger = Logger.getLogger("tutorialPU");
   23:         logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
   24:     }
   25:         
   26:     public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
   27:         EntityManager manager = threadLocal.get();      
   28:         if (manager == null || !manager.isOpen()) {
   29:             manager = emf.createEntityManager();
   30:             threadLocal.set(manager);
   31:         }
   32:         return manager;
   33:     }
   34:     
   35:      public static void closeEntityManager() {
   36:         EntityManager em = threadLocal.get();
   37:         threadLocal.set(null);
   38:         if (em != null) em.close();
   39:     }
   40:     
   41:     public static void beginTransaction() {
   42:         getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();
   43:     }
   44:     
   45:     public static void commit() {
   46:         getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();
   47:     }  
   48:     
   49:     public static Query createQuery(String query) {
   50:         return getEntityManager().createQuery(query);
   51:     }
   52:     
   53:     public static void log(String info, Level level, Throwable ex) {
   54:         logger.log(level, info, ex);
   55:     }
   56:     
   57: }
```

my persistence.xml is:

```
    <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

      <persistence-unit name="OrderEJB" type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>movieDatabase</jta-data-source>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>   
      </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

i have two problems:
1-when i call the getEntityManager().persist(anObject);
it does not save any thing in database neither produce any error in container log!!
2-every things seems ok but when i redploy the application(without restarting server) every operations of JPA fail with the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The type [null] is not the expected
[EntityType] for the key class [class entity.MyClass].
```

if i restart the server every thing is okay!!!

i am using netbeans 6.9.1, glasfish 3.1, eclipselink (JPA 2.0)
so how could i resolve my problems?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. you have to commit the EntityManager's transaction that the changes will be made persistent
   (try `manager.getTransaction().commit()`)
2. Post the complete stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour of eclipselink seems to be that insert queries are done only before select queries, when you call flush() or at the end of the transaction (auto-flush on commit)

there are persistence providers with a different behaviour (hibernate for example). but in your case try calling em.flush() or close the transaction (or make sure you container does that properly)